# predict a single value

Tags: stata, prediction

I'm a newbie of Stata. Let's say I have:

```
reg Y x1 x2
```

Now I have the regression coefficients displayed.
How can I make a prediction from specific values, say x1=10 and x2=20, without having to type manually the equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
display _b[_cons] + _b[x1] * 10 + _b[x2] * 20
```

is not that painful. Otherwise use `set obs` to increase the number of observations, insert the new values and then run `predict reg`